# Minimizing AX - B where both A and X are variable matrices.

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem of the form:

$$\text{minimize} \: \lVert AX - B \rVert^2_2$$

Subject to

$$A \geq 0 \\ X \geq 0.$$

Both $A$ and $X$ are variable and $B$ is a constant.

So essentially the problem is to factorize $B$ into $A$ and $X$ but unlike the typical recommender system problem, we know $B$ in its entirety.

Does this fall under any optimization domain? How would I go about solving this to find the best $A$ and $X$? The only approach I currently have is gradient descent but I doubt it's gonna find a good solution.

Edit: The dimensions of $A$ and $X$ are predetermined and not a free parameter.

Every element of $B$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Does $A\geq 0$ mean that every element of $A$ are positive ? Do you have any dimensional constraint ? If not you can take $A=I$, $X=B$ whenever $B\geq 0$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. A and X are of a specified dimension and that's not up to me. The elements of A, X need to be nonnegative and the elements of B are nonnegative.

Comment: The wikipedia article lists some algorithms https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization